# What does ActionBar#setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in Android Support library?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I know what `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` does, but what is `setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` for I can only wonder. No documentation found, cannot find anything except it is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method is only available in the Support Action Bar, not in the "native" ActionBar class available since Android 3. More importantly, it is annotated with `@hide` in the source, meaning it is not part of the official API for third-party developers. That is why it is nowhere documented by Google. You should just not use it.

Having a deeper look into the sources, I found the method implemented in `WindowDecorActionBar`:

```
public void setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean enable) {
    if (!mDisplayHomeAsUpSet) {
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

So basically it does exactly the same as using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`, but only if the value has not yet been set manually using the said function.

tldr: you should always use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` and ignore the default method.